# Vmware virtual machine creation from live partition

Tags: virtualization, vmware-player

I have a dual booted system with Windows Xp and Opensuse 10.3. I want to create a virtual machine from the installed Opensuse 10.3 as I have a lot of software and settings in the linux partition and run the virtual machine from Xp. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VMware Converter](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) is free and will get the job done. It supports hot cloning so you can keep using the system while it converts too.

Comment: Bear in mind that if you boot the VM while the physical machine is online, you'll get hostname, IP and MAC address conflicts. I tend to boot the VM without a network card the first time, so I can check it works fine before having to shutdown the real machine.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use windows nor vmware, so I am just guessing here... but I would say that a possible way to proceed is to create your virtual machine in windows and fresh installl Opensuse 10.3 there. Then you could copy all the relevant directories (/home, /var, /usr/bin, etc...) from the "real" installation to the fake one.

There are also specific tools like [this one](http://www.vmware.com/products/converter/) to achieve the same goal, but from the website I could not easily guess if it is free for personal use or not.